# Always positive two variable function

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone help me how to prove that function $$f(x,y)=-x^4+6x^3+(y-1)^2-x^2(11+2y-y^2)-2x(y^2-2y-3)$$ is always positive, where $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in[0,1]$? What do I need to consider?

Comment: What do you know about $f$?

Comment: I know that $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in [0,1]$

Comment: What else? We need more information to prove $f$ is always posiive.

Comment: THis is the function $$f(x,y)=-x^4+6x^3+(y-1)^2-x^2(11+2y-y^2)-2x(y^2-2y-3)$$

Comment: That is information you **must** add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) < 0$ for all $(x,y) \in (0,1)\times(0,1)$. So you only need to check the points where $y=1$, which is a one-variable calculus problem.

In general, the first thing to try is to look for critical points, so calculating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ should be the first reflex.